# Why is there a hole in one of the layer of an airplane's windows?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, cabin-pressure, windows, feature-identification

On a commercial airliner, there is a hole in one of the layer of the passenger windows.

See here:

[image: Airplane window]

and here:

[image: Another airplane window]

Or in more detail:

[image: Zoom on hole in airplane window]

Can you explain the physical reasons for this design choice?

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but the question is adressed here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/673/95

Comment: @yankeekilo Well spotted. The title and slightly different subject of the other question made me not find it when searching before asking. Since there is not a lot of details in the answer that address it http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/681/1599 I suggest we keep this one open.

Comment: I agree with @Guillaume

Answer (score 27):

Aircraft windows are multiple layers thick. The side facing the passengers is just a plastic sheet, since they wouldn't want the passengers scratching up the actual expensive glass window. Beyond the inner pane there are two actual structural window panes. The outer one is normally the one bearing the load, while the inner one serves as a backup.

However, since pressure changes in the cabin during the flight, it's also necessary to **equalize the pressure between the window panes**, and hence the little hole. A hole of that size would not jeopardize pressurization even if the outer pane blew out. Note the label "Breather Hole" in the diagram below.

[image]

There is a rubber seal around the outside of the two panes so it would be a bit of a pain to open a hole to cavity from the side. Apart from that, the windows are pretty tight together and by keeping it where it is there is nothing in the vicinity such as dust that could gradually be pulled in.

Since the air in between the panes is colder, it's not unusual to see ice crystals forming around the hole as the more humid cabin air enters the cavity.

[image: 787window]
<sub>(source: [gentex.com](https://www.gentex.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/default/wysiwyg_imageupload/air_diagram_1.jpg))</sub>

*787 Window*

This diagram includes the electric shade system of the 787 which is fairly similar. Since the two outermost panes carry no structural purpose you can just have them equalize air as you please.

Comment: So on the 787, where the hole would be? On the interior window pane?

Comment: I'm not sure how the 787 is, but here's a picture: http://www.airlinereporter.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/787-wing.jpg and it looks like it might have two holes, but i'm not sure where these are located. i'm not sure if you can just drill through these electrochromic panels, or if there might be a bypass on the side to fulfill the same purpose...

Comment: I'm still confused by the need of the 2 panes if an hole in the interior pane make the pressure adjust to the cabin.

Comment: There's a seal on every window and therefore every pressure until the final 'real' window has to be equalized since otherwise these would blow or crack. does this answer your question? :)

Comment: No, sorry, still a bit curious! Totally agree on the seal on every part until the last (outer) window pane for pressure equalisation. But I'm now wondering why the Structural Cabin Window System would have more than one pane? Is it to control the pressure change rate in case of damage on the outer pane as hinted here http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/681/1599 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is for safety/redundancy purposes. Both are designed to be strong enough for the pressure difference, but in case there's a structural defect in one, it will not lead to the complete blowout and loss of cabin pressure. I'm very sure the cockpit windows are double paned as well for the same reason. Looking on a few forums, it seems to be that the outer panel is designed to carry the load, since there's a very small bleed between the inner window and cabin air to equalize the space inbetween.

Comment: Wouldn't another key purpose of the glass layering be to limit heat loss?

Comment: I've borrowed some of your images [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26381/12102).