# What is this plastic device inside the plane window?

Tags: airliner, feature-identification, windows

[image: Plastic device between layers of the window]

I saw this on a recent domestic flight. It was glued on all the windows of the plane, behind the first layer of plastic. What is it and its purpose?

Comment: What flight number? Do you happen to know the model of the plane?

Comment: @vasin1987 it either has a winglet (which narrows it down by... not a lot) or was flying in close formation with another plane. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

I've found it on the 737, both the -800 and Max as far as I've looked. It's even [noticeable from the outside](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Boeing_737-800_(8373688357).jpg).

The related patent from 2005 is [US7267302B2 Window airflow damper](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7267302B2/). It solves an issue with severe window fogging. Basically it's a device that replaces the [usual *breather* hole](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2454/14897) by putting the hole on top and covering it with a damper.

There is a blog post about it called *[New cabin window design & installation](http://www.sjap.nl/new-cabin-window-design-installation/):*

> A new cabin window assy has been introduced due to the fogging problems we all encounter on the 737NG’s. The new cabin window assy has a breather hole **at the TOP,** compared to the bottom vent hole at the BOTTOM on the old panes.
>
> The new window assemblies use thicker outer panes, redesigned seals with integral stiffening ring, and an **airflow damper** over the middle pane vent hole (...)

[image]