# Why is it hard to see G1000 with sunglasses?

Tags: avionics, glass-cockpit, g1000

I got checked out in the G1000 172 at my flight school just so I could schedule to fly when the two steam gauge 172s were booked. I'm very impressed by the G1000, but I can't wear sunglasses when I fly the NAVIII. This is with the avionics dial on the lighting panel turned all the way up.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is it my sunglasses?

Comment: Are they polarized?

Comment: They are indeed

Comment: The FAA is on record as being against polarized sunglasses. See page 5 of the following publication: https://www.faa.gov/pilots/safety/pilotsafetybrochures/media/sunglasses.pdf, which I should have read but didn't and now have a pair of sunglasses that are useless for glass cockpits.

Comment: [Related  question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13638/19)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The screens are LCDs, which have a polarized filter layer over them. That layer is usually placed at a 45° so they are misaligned with your polarized sunglasses which are aligned vertically. You can confirm this is the problem by turning your sunglasses at different angles and see if the screen changes.

Comment: Bingo! Can't wait to test this out.

Comment: The polarization on the sunglasses is probably the issue. It's not a good idea to fly with polarized sunglasses on anyway. It can reduce the glare off an airplane when that glare might be the queue that saves your life.

Comment: This is 100% what's up. I modified this answer to be a little more certain about things.

Comment: Gratuitous extra info: A polarization filter is a key part of an LCD. Liquid crystal itself can only change the polarization of the light going through it; it's the polarization filter that then blocks some of the light making pixels appear light or dark : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display#Overview

Comment: However, it would be easy to "de-polarize" the light coming from an LCD, so you could still read it at any angle. A plastic foil of a cigarette packet mounted on a display at the correct angle works well enough to demonstrate the effect. I don't understand why manufacturers don't spend a few cents for such a  foil (of course, higher quality than the foil from a cigarette pack...)

Comment: @RyanBurnette: Ahem "cue" ;)

Comment: I read a few other sources that say flying with polarized glasses is fine. In the end we'll all make our own choice about it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Planes are made of metal, but usually are painted, too. The paint generates polarized glare. About the LCD: Of course, polarization is the principle of work inside an LCD. But you can convert the linear polarized light coming from the display into circular polarized light, which is not affected by polarizing sunglasses. As said, a simple foil on top of the display is enough. My opinion: The blue of the sky is also partially polarized and so shaded by glasses. Clouds and other objects stay bright and are better visible, which is a clear _pro_ for polarized glasses.

Comment: @sweber I was under the impression that the thin layer of paint wouldn't cause polarization but it seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, it is not the paint that causes polarization. Whenever light is reflected from a surface at an angle (not perpendicular), it is polarized.

Comment: @sweber: Polarized sunglasses are polarized so that they filter out _reflections_, mainly from horizontal surfaces. Most of the time that is what you want, but not when looking for other aircraft.

Comment: @JanHudec Sure, it's not paint that causes polarization *per se*. Rather, metals cause non-polarization and I was under the mistaken impression that painted metal had enough of the properties of metal that it would also cause non-polarization.

Comment: Thanks guys. Did not know what the polarization filter did in lcd's, just knew there was one. You learn something new every day. Edited answer to reflect.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, yes, metals don't cause polarization on reflection, but once the paint is opaque (and that's it's point) it is the paint and not the metal that reflects the light, so the reflection becomes polarized (I wonder what a metalic paint does though).

Comment: First off, metallic paints actually don't have any metal (there are some paints with high metal content to make them conductive for electronic shielding, but they're not very pretty). Metallic silver paint is just a specific shade of grey in a gloss base with mica particles suspended in it to provide that metallic glitter. So on a plane painted silver, the reflection is 100% paint. The mica flakes can cause a scatter effect on polarization because they're oriented at different angles, but it's minor compared to the reflection off the high-gloss surface.