# Where can I find a video about making F-16 jet fighter canopies?

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer, f-16, canopy

I'm searching for a video of the manufacturing process for an F-16 jet fighter canopy. Can anybody help me?  Does anybody know where these canopies are manufactured?

Comment: Well, way back when the F-16 was built by General Dynamics at Carswell AFB, Ft. Worth Texas. Fun Facts: *Strategic Air Command* starring Jimmy Stewart was filmed there. There is a B-36 in the lake at the end of the runway. Last time I looked you could still see its tail.

Comment: P.S. There are (were?) 6 pristine F-16's at the salvage yard. Maybe you can get a replacement canopy there. These were flow directly from the plant (Carswell AFB, above) to the boneyard in Arizona. Originally destined for Pakistan, the Pakistanis did something to tick us off.

Comment: You might find your answer, or at least a good direction in the answers to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/what-kind-of-materials-is-being-used-for-fighter-jets-glass-shields).

Comment: Some [pictures](http://www.digisol.ch/content/files/fotos_mecaplex_ag_grenchen.pdf?ts=428427374652778), from the name of the manufacturer provided in the answer to the question linked by @FreeMan.

Comment: @mins 1-handed, sideways, free-hand (no jig or template) routing looks like a great way to ruin a work piece and potentially remove a knee cap! (5th image down.) Yikes!

Comment: @FreeMan: Also [this video](https://www.srf.ch/news/regional/aargau-solothurn/grenchner-firma-hofft-auf-grossen-auftrag-aus-schweden). I don't know, this is hand-crafted, but the quality must be there else they wouldn't have many renowned customers. This seems to be for prototypes and unique parts, not for mass production.