# Why are the cabin inner windows so flexible?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

A few days ago I flew on an A321. While pointing to something outside my finger touched the window. It made a crackling sound and felt quit flexible.
I was able to push it at least 5mm without any effort (I didn't wanted to push further because I thought I might break it).

On the way back, I flew on a B737 and the same thing applied on its windows as well.

I'm pretty sure it's that thin because of the weight but is there any other reason for such a thin (and probably fragile) inner glass which could be easily damaged by a passenger by mistake?

Comment: Just to put your mind at ease - there is no way you would have broken it. It would be a heluva coup for terrorists if they could depressurize an aircraft with little more than a window seat and their bare hands :D

Comment: It's not the real window, behind the panel that you pushed are one or two layers of hard transparent material that you won't be able to easily deflect. Also refer to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/681/21091).

Comment: It probably is Polycarbonate, way stronger that you think...

Comment: I'm aware of the fact, that there are more than only this layer of glass and that the outer layer is thicker. I was just surprised that is was that flexible.

Comment: The layer you touched is just an inexpensive and easily replaced screen to keep passengers from scratching up the costly and more permanently installed transparent pressure bulkhead. - I am guessing the flexible inner screen can be replaced without the level of re-certification required to replace the pressure resistant panes.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Suggest you make that an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I will if I can find any supporting authority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inner window is just a plastic protective cover, so that you don't touch the glass, which is probably very cold at altitude. You'll notice on the inner window there is a tiny hole at the bottom to equalize pressure and prevent condensation.

[image]

See this [article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_eye/2015/05/29/what_s_that_thing_why_are_there_holes_in_airplane_windows.html) that explains it